# Save form to display it after a redirect to other page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a page where the user insert some information about a client. He may need to add a new contact (this contact had a lot of information ), so the user will be redirected to the create contact action.

My problem is how to save the first information about the client which are not submitted yet and display it after adding of the contact?

Answer (score 0):

Create a mock client or a temporary ID, and then come back to it and fill it with real data.

Comment: the form is not complete so when adding client it will throw exceptions